# How can I express the following line of HTML code in Xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

the line of code is the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data_mentalidad_web_35084" value='[{"name":"Extensor Cable Riser PEC 300 PCI-E x16 ","id":"35084","price":"29990","brand":"Deepcool  \u00ae ","category":"Tarjetas Gr\u00e1ficas","variant":"","quantity":1,"position":1}]'>
```

of which I only want what is marked in bold:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data_mentalidad_web_35084" value='[{"name":"***Extensor Cable Riser PEC 300 PCI-E x16*** ","id":"35084","price":"***29990***","brand":"Deepcool  \u00ae ","category":"***Tarjetas Gr\u00e1ficas***","variant":"","quantity":***1***,"position":1}]'>
```

Comment: `"quantity":***1***` is invalid syntax. To pot stars around the one you'd need a string: `f"***{1}***"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` multiple time with `and` like below :

```
//input[contains(@value,'Extensor Cable Riser PEC 300 PCI-E x16') and contains(@value,'29990') and contains(@value,'Tarjetas Gr\u00e1ficas') and contains(@value,'1')]
```

You will also need to understand the value is an `attribute` and it has only one value, wrapped inside `[]`, don't get confused with that.

Comment: `type="hidden"` so Selenium won't be able to find it straight away. Cross check your answer once.

Comment: @DebanjanB :  the question is solely asking for XPath, Selenium is not the only tool that uses XPath.

Comment: Still the output will be _`[{"name":"Extensor Cable Riser PEC 300 PCI-E x16 ","id":"35084","price":"29990","brand":"Deepcool  \u00ae ","category":"Tarjetas Gr\u00e1ficas","variant":"","quantity":1,"position":1}]`_ not **`1`** as OP expects.

Comment: @DebanjanB: There is an invention called JSON array and how to convert string to JSON array and retrieve the data.

Comment: Precisely that was OP's main question here.

Comment: @DebanjanB : You really need reading skill, read this `How can I express the following line of HTML code in Xpath?`

Comment: Reread the question with some borrowed reading skill : _`of which I only want what is marked in bold`_

Comment: @DebanjanB : read my comment "There is an invention called JSON array and how to convert string to JSON array and retrieve the data" - there isn't anything to argue here.